# asp.net dropdown null value stores 0 instead of null

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add a title for dropdown menu.
The problem is that if the data is null, it automatically update as 0.
This doesn't happen when I create the data row.
The date type is int32. 
The funny thing is that I can insert null but I can not update as null.

My solution was to add two listitems.
One is value="". This is for initial data. (create)
Another is value="0". This is for after update.
However this is not pretty solution.

How come integer stores 0 instead of null when I update the data?
It seems possible to store null when I create the row...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="addl" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("a") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="-Select-"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">test1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">test2</asp:ListItem>                      
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="-Select-"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

what would be the best solution for dropdown menu title if the data type is integer?
If it's string, I can simply add value="" and works just time.
Integer stores 0 if it's null and I have to also create null in  order to avoid error in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

`Int32` is not a Nullable type and by default will equal 0 (even if not initialized).  Try using `Int32?` which is Nullable, or use some other index to indicate the Create option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what `int` you are trying to update, but if it's a variable that you have control over you could look at changing it from a standard `int` to a nullable `int`.  This can be as simple as changing this:

```
int i;
```

to this:

```
int? i;
```

Comment: Data type in SQL Server is int. Update parameter is    <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="addl" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>

Comment: If it's in insert Parameters, I can insert null.            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="addl" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>